# complex number sets and relations

Tags: relations

Sets can be defined for complex numbers. If so, then will there be any kind of relations which will be defined for complex number sets , like reflexive relation or transitive relation which are defined for real numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define relations, including reflexive and transitive relations on any set, even if the set is empty.
The simplest example of relation on complex numbers that is both reflexive and transitive is equality.